# Adding geocode module to kohana 3.3

Tags: php, geocode, kohana-3.3

I have a problem with using geocode module.
I used several complete modules, for example [kohana-geocode](https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-geocode).
I copied folder to modules, added `config/geocode.php` to config in application and added module in `bootstrap.php` but the result is:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Geocode' not found.

Do I have to do anything else to install this module or this version is wrong?

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating `init.php` in module directory to config *autoload* or *include* required files manually?

> **Init.php** [<kbd>link</kbd>](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/modules)
>
> When a module is activated, if an `init.php` file exists in that module's directory, it is included. This is the ideal place to have a module include routes or other initialization necessary for the module to function. The Userguide and Codebench modules have `init.php` files you can look at.